# USA refugee travel document to travel to UK

Tags: visas, usa, uk, standard-visitor-visas, zimbabwean-citizens

I am planning to visit the UK on a USA travel document but there’s nowhere I am able to find information about visas: I’m a Zimbabwean but using a USA refugee travel document do I need to apply for a UK visa before I travel or I can they just give them on arrival.

Comment: If you enter your details here, you can get an answer on what you need https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&country=/GB

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you hold a Travel Document Under the Convention of 1951, inputting your data into [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&country=/GB), the database used by airlines yields the following results:

> ## United Kingdom - Destination Visa
>
> Visa required.

You will need to apply for a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa).

Answer (score 1):

Using this tool https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y and selecting ‘Stateless or Refugee’ for the nationality will give you the answer (which is that you need a visa).